# php://input is outputting an empty string

Tags: php, io

I am sending this request from Insomnia (a PostMan like software). I am sending a simple XML file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

And on **Header** i only have **Content-Type: application/xml**
I am sending this to an php file which contains this code:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');

echo "<pre>";
print_r(htmlspecialchars($xml));
echo "</pre>";
```

Which is outputting an empty string. On my local server it's outputting the xml file how it should be.

My settings on my paid server are:
[image]

My Insomnia screen looks like this:
[image]
[image]

The output comes from this code:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

Outputs the empty array and:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']) && $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] == 'application/xml') {
    echo "application/xml";
}
```

Outputs "application/xml".

**Answer**: it turns out in my case i should have wrote the address with **HTTPS** instead of HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many factors can affect this:

- It might happen because you are accessing incorrect site url. Eg: http://mysite and https://mysite are two different sites.
- It might happen if you are sending your request as form data.
- Also if `allow_url_fopen` is set to `Off`. To allow url fopen you just need to add a line in `php.ini`: `ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);`
- This might even happen if you have a redirect from `mysite.com` to `something.mysite.com` or vice-versa. To verify any redirects, you should first check the `.htaccess`. If there is no redirect using `.htaccess`, then add some kind of count in super global like `$_SESSION` and increment it. If the count is more than 1, then you have a redirect.
- You might be able find some information in server logs.